# Display list of React Components into a table

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component called Widget and I want to display a list of widgets as a table.

Let's say the array of widgets looks like `A, B, C, D, E, F, G` and I will allow up to 3 TD per Table Row. So the result will look like the following.

```
A  B  C 

D  E  F

G
```

Although the simple line skip can be done with css by using Ul but I have to us e a table for header labels.

I tried making the original array into list of arrays like `[[A,B,C], [D,E,F], [G]]`:

```
{
    chunkedPartsArray.map((chunk, ind) => {
          return (<tr>
             {
                  chunk.map((obj, ind) => {
                      return {obj}
                  })
             }
             </tr>)
     })
}
```

The above code gives me the following warning

```
Uncaught Error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with
keys {obj}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array 
instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-
ons. Check the render method of WidgetsTab.
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0):

You should wrap your widgets within a `td` element. I have shown a demonstration using  characters.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    var chunkedPartsArray = [['A','B','C'], ['D','E','F'], ['G']]

return (
          <tbody>{chunkedPartsArray.map((chunk, ind) => {        
          console.log(chunk);
          return (<tr>
             {
                  chunk.map((obj, ind) => {
                      console.log(obj);
                      return <td>{obj}</td>
                  })
             }
             </tr>)
          })
          }</tbody>
   )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.0.1/react-dom.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function out there and return html.
in react we need wrap the component into a div if it is more than one.
so you need a placeholder for child and return from function.

```
//in a file after imports 
function getChunkedParts(chunk, ind){

function getChunks(obj, ind){return (<td>{obj}</td>)}

var chunks =chunk.map((obj, ind) =>getChunks(obj, ind));
return (<tr>{chunks} </tr>)
}}

//parent render
render{
var ChunkedParts =    chunkedPartsArray.map((chunk, ind) =>getChunkedParts(chunk, ind);
return(<table>{ChunkedParts }</table>)
}
```